# Definition syntax with else statement in Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, syntax, ruby-2.1

Will ruby support a syntax with the following code:

```
class Test
 def test
  #some code here
 else
  #some code here
 end
end
```

I found this syntax to be valid and ruby interpreter did not flag any exceptions for this.
If this is valid can anyone explain the usage for this syntax.

Currently using Ruby 2.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid Ruby syntax but for `rescue` look example:

```
#exm.rb
class Test
 def test
  #some code here
 else
  #some code here
 end
end
```

and run (`-w turn warnings on for your script`):

```
$ ruby -w exm.rb
exm.rb:7: warning: else without rescue is useless
```

check syntax (`-c  check syntax only`):

```
ruby -c exm.rb
arra.rb:7: warning: else without rescue is useless
Syntax OK
```

with `rescue`:

```
#exm.rb
class Test
  def test
    #some code here
  rescue
    #some code here
  else
    #some code here
  end
end
```

check syntax:

```
ruby -c exm.rb
Syntax OK
```

Read about [`begin + rescue + else`](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/8/begin-else)

Comment: I don't know how often I have written this on SO already, but apparently it cannot be repeated enough: **read the warnings**!